# How do you change the testing default driver for a Cucumber test in Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

In the documentation provided by [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), you can change the default_driver on a specific test group:

```
describe 'some stuff which requires js', :js => true do
  it 'will use the default js driver'
  it 'will switch to one specific driver', :driver => :selenium
end
```

What if I wanted to do this for a specific cucumber test group? How would I add those parameters?

```
When /^I do something$/  do
  fill_in "a_text_box", :with => "stuff"
  fill_in "another_text_box", :with => "another_thing"
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cucumber, I've done this in two steps:

In `/features/support/env.rb`, place the following line:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Then in the cucumber feature, just before the specific scenario, add `@javascript` just before the scenario -- like this:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Successful sign in - with no flash message if using current firefox
When I'm using a current version of Firefox
When I visit the practitioner home page with "jane.doe@example.com"'s token
Then I should be signed in as practitioner "Jane Doe"
And I should be on the practitioner activities welcome page
And I should not see a flash message warning me I have an unsupported browser
```

This tells cucumber to use the `javascript` driver when it runs that particular scenario.

This is how I've done this using Capybara Webkit -- I'm sure other drivers are similar.

Comment: Capybara now automatically switches to any named driver that matches a tag on your scenario, rather than this being a special case for `@javascript`.  e.g. if you create a `tablet` driver and tag your scenario with `@tablet`, then the `tablet` driver will automatically get used!

Comment: Thanks for expanding on the answer.

Comment: Does this make the test specific to the scenario and revert back to default after?

Comment: Yes. It's for that scenario only.

Comment: @JonM does this mean I could just define a `Capybara.jabberwocky_driver` in my `env.rb` and then just tag my tests with `@jabberwocky`?

Answer (score 5):

```
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit # temporarily select different driver
#... tests ...
Capybara.use_default_driver       # switch back to default driver
```

Comment: Would I put `Capybara.current_driver = :webkit` right before the When group and then the `Capybara.user_default_driver` after?

Answer (score 2):

With cucumber you can achieve this using tags. For example, if your default driver is webkit but you want to run some scenario with selenium you can tag it with `@selenium`. This works with `gem 'selenium-webdriver'` by default

In general, if you want to switch to some other driver (Headless chrome in this example), put the following code in `features/support/drivers.rb`:

```
# features/support/drivers.rb
Around '@headless_chrome' do |scenario, block|
  begin
    Capybara.current_driver = :headless_chrome # temporarily select headless chrome
    block.call
  ensure
    Capybara.use_default_driver                # switch back to default webkit driver
  end
end
```